# Autoscaling Existing Intance Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an instance on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

The default setup performs well for about 100 concurrent users.

I would like to know if Compute engine is able to add resources to the instance as needed (when the system spikes)

I have seen information on how to do it where you have to use the instance template with a startup script. but I am not really sure how to distribute the different services (redis, mysql, nginx, php-fpm) accross the different instances.

I am getting to the point where I think i need some help but other than emailing google I don't even know how to do that.

Please help. I am not afraid of reading docs (been doing that for 3 days now) so even if you can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your services into different instances.

A simple start would be to put your mysql and redis on a new instance, then change your application to use that new instance for the mysql and redis connections.

Then you would need to use a HTTP load balancer with an autoscale instance group which is very straightforward to setup https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/

If your applications is writing to disk you would also have to change your application so it writes in Google Cloud Storage for example.

Comment: thank you. still working on this but that at least gives me some direction